# Make a class filterable on a delegated attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application in RoR4 that has the following model:

```
# Quotation model
class Quotation < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :request
  has_one :booking
  has_one :review
  has_one :coupon, class_name: 'Coupons::Models::CouponRedemption'

  delegate :artist, to: :request
  delegate :user, to: :request
end
```

I am trying to make a query that can find show all Quotation objects that are linked with a certain user. I tried to do it with the following:

```
  # Scope to filter based on user
  scope :_user, -> (user_id) { where user: user_id }
```

This however returns "undefined method `user'", do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: why you scope name starts with underscore?

Comment: Doesn't realy have a reason, but I could also use it without an underscore.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have a user column in the quotations table. The delegation just hands the method down to request. Like this:

```
def user
  request.user
end
```

Instead you can include the request in the query:

```
scope :_user, -> (user_id) { includes(:request).where(requests: { user: user_id}) }
```